# CSS: "line-height" combined with "list-style" does not work like expected in Firefox

Tags: css

Firefox ignores the `line-height` setting in this case:

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: "– ";
  line-height: 30%; /* Firefox ignores that */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

How is it possible to fix that? There also should be in Firefox these 30 percent.

If one list item gets longer than one line, there still should be this typical indent at the beginning.

Comment: @return_false line-height affect block elements

Comment: it seems that firefox doesn't allow you to have small line-height. Even if you try line-height:1px on li it's not working

Comment: 30% line-height doesn't really make sense - that would mean 30% of the font-size which would make the lines overlap...

Comment: Some browsers will cut off the text if it is larger than the line height. A good strategy here would be to give the LI element a line height of 1em and then set the spacing between the list items with a grid.

Comment: Maybe worth seeing if there's a bug on the Firefox bugzilla for this and raising one if there isn't. I believe Firefox are in the process of changing how default list markers are rendered, from "magic" graphics to regular font glyphs, so this might get fixed along the way.

Comment: @Alohci – I have no account there, but please feel free to report a bug 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it different using pseudo element. It seems to work fine on Firefox:

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  line-height: 30%; 
}

ul li::before {
  content:"– ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is no longer a list

Comment: @return_false it's what then ?

Comment: A block element

Comment: @return_false not sure what you mean by "block element" but the code I provided gives the same output/result than the OP code

Comment: Might as well use a div at that point because your code removes the list functionality

Comment: @return_false no it doesn't. The HTML code is the same, and that's what counts semantically

Comment: @return_false my code removes nothing, I am still using a list and the `li` still have `list-item` in their display value, I simply changed the *style* of the *list*

Comment: Believe what you want but when you set list style to none that removes the list functionality. notice you need to create your own bullets.

Comment: @return_false I will certainly not believe your comment but if you give me an authoritative resource proving your claim, I may believe it. Until then, my list is a *list*

Comment: Alright, i was wrong about that. It is still a list.

Comment: Thank you! Now there is the problem if one list item gets longer than one line, there is no indent for the following lines ...

Comment: @Anna_B it was already the case with your code using list-style-position:inside ..

Comment: Oh wow, you are right! Sorry. Is it still possible to do it like that?

Comment: @Anna_B you can try negative text-indent: https://jsfiddle.net/2gcx9Lsy/